# Telerik MVC Extensions, grid, chrome and vertical scroll bar disappearing

Tags: telerik-mvc

We've noticed lately that the grids in our website as well the ones on the demo page for the grid show the vertical scroll bar until the page finishes loading and then disappears. It appears to be adding 'overflow: hidden' to the table which has the effect of removing the scroll bar. When I remove this css (inside Chrome debugger) the scroll bar re-appears. I have confirmed this behavior on multiple users' systems.

Anyone know of a fix for this? I have a feeling this is something Telerik will have to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is happening because of a setting located in the Chrome debugger settings called ‘Emulate touch events’. When the Telerik grid detects a touch enabled browser it adds the overflow:hidden to the grid. In my case, a majority of the laptops at my work are touch screen enabled and so the 'bug' manifests on those machines.